# Drupal 7 export suddenly increased by 10 gigs

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7

I was placed in charge of my companies website, which is built on drupal 7, and I have been creating daily exports of th SQL database. Recently, the export jumped in size by 10 gigs and slowed down the export signifigantly. I trackd down th issue to two SQL tables, cache_advagg_aggregate and cache_form.

In addition to this problem, I can no longer directly access admin/config or the status page. When I try to access either, it just brings up a white page or 404.

I am not sure if they are related but the timing was the same. Does anyone have any advice on how I can clear these specific caches and/or what may be triggering this white screen only on these two specific pages?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Check module `dblog` , try to disable it and test. You have a application error or redirect caus emay some issues ?

Comment: I couldn't find that module in the list, could there be a different one that is causing a similar issue?

Comment: You can truncate all tables which begin by "cache" in your database , are you using memcache ?

Comment: I am not using memcache, would you recommend it? I tried to truncate all caches and it bricked my site, I will try to selectively clear each table one by one next. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: I was able to truncate the problem caches and the backup is back to normal but I still get th white screen of death on the status report, admin and CRON pages.